# Dog DNA test from stool not swabs

Tags: breeds, tests

Does anyone know of a dog dna test that can provide heritage details from stool samples instead of by mouth swab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sort of depends on what your intent is. You can expect dog feces to be highly contaminated with DNA not from the dog, and therefore I would guess that you probably couldn't get a truly accurate DNA profile of the dog that way. However, if you already have accurate DNA profiles of dogs from mouth swabs, you may be able to get enough DNA from the feces to guess which dog in your database produced the waste with a reasonable level of accuracy. There are businesses that provide that service, with the intent of helping communal living spaces such as apartment complexes catch residents who aren't cleaning up after their pets. Poo Prints is one such business.